# Page source is not updating after clicking button

Tags: ios, python-3.x, appium, ui-testing

I am using **Appium + Python** on `iOS` real device.

**Scenario**: There are multiple `XCUIElementTypeCell` on the page. Once I click first cell Next button. First cell minimize and Second cell show all details with Next Button.

**Issue**: When I click first cell next button. Second cell next button does not show up on page source. 
Workaround: I tried work around as go back to home page and come back to original page and all element shows up in page source.

I am looking solution or any help to refresh page source or `XCUIElement` source without changing page.

Thanks for help.

> Code Sample:

```
el2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//XCUIElementTypeButton[@name=\"NEXT\"])[1]")
el2.click()
el3 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//XCUIElementTypeButton[@name=\"NEXT\"])[2]")
el3.click()
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Did you tried to use **ExplicitWait** for the element after clicking first button?

Comment: Did you check if you have other window handles that could contain that element?

Comment: Also, check if the drivers current handle is still in the window handle list.

Comment: I did some research on it. XCUIElement does not work well with Dynamic element on App page. XCUIElement and Appium only load all element when App page is loaded after that any dynamic element added on that page does not reflect. 
I had no luck to resolve this issue.